# SFMC: how to make API call to 'update contact' in SSJS activity

Tags: api, json, ssjs, mobilepush, postman

I downloaded a POSTMAN collection with plenty of pre-configured API call.
I managed to succesfully request a token from our API and afterwards do 'update contact' in order to update a single record in 'MobilePush Demographics'. So I can change values for single records using the POSTMAN tool.

Now I am trying to 'transfer' the whole thing into a SSJS activity as I need to completely automated something similar.
That is where I am getting stuck, despite searching for a while and trying different things to get it done myself.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Strict-Transport-Security","max-age=200"); 
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-XSS-Protection","1; mode=block"); 
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-Frame-Options","Deny"); 
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("X-Content-Type-Options","nosniff"); 
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Referrer-Policy","strict-origin-when-cross-origin"); 
Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Content-Security-Policy","default-src 'self'"); 
  
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.5");

//authorize
var account_id = "ENTERACCIDHERE"; //accountID parentBU
var grant_type = "client_credentials";
var client_id = "ENTERIDHERE";
var client_secret = "ENTERSECRETHERE";
var authEndpoint = "ENTEREINPOINTHERE/"; //tenant-specific endpoint


// Get API AccessToken
var url = authEndpoint + 'v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';
var  payload = '{"grant_type":"' + grant_type + '",';
payload += '"client_id":"' + client_id + '",';
payload += '"client_secret":"' + client_secret + '",';
payload += '"account_id":"' + account_id + '"}';
var accessToken = "";

try {
   // create token
   var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Patch(url, contentType, payload);
   var statusCode = accessTokenResult["StatusCode"];
   var response = accessTokenResult["Response"][0];
   accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).access_token;
   //Write(accessToken);

 }
 catch (err)  {
    Write("<br>url " + url);
    Write("<br>contentType: " + contentType);
    Write("<br>" + payload);
    Write("<br>error");
}
  
if(accessToken !='')
{

//execute
var url1 = 'OURENDPOINT/contacts/v1/contacts'; //tenant-specific endpoint
var contentType1 = 'application/json'; 
var payload1 = '{"contactKey":"ENTERCONTACTKEYHERE","attributeSets":[{"name":"MobilePush Demographics","items":[{"values":[{"name":"Device ID","value":"ENTERDEVICEIDHERE"},{"name":"Application","value":"ENTERAPPLICATIONHERE"},{"name":"Last Name","value":"HiTest"},{"name":"Modified Date","value":"Mar 23 2020 7:51AM"},{"name":"Created Date","value":"JAN 17 2020 7:39AM"}]}]}]}'; //
var headerNames = ["Authorization"]; 
var s1="Bearer ";
var headerValues = s1.concat(accessToken); 
  try {
    var result = HTTP.Patch(url1, contentType1, payload1, headerNames, headerValues);
    var statusCode1 = result["StatusCode"];
    var response1 = result["Response"][0];
    var operationID1 = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response1).operationID;
    var responseDateTime1 = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response1).responseDateTime;
    var requestServiceMessageID1 = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response1).requestServiceMessageID;
    }
   catch (err)  {
    Write("<br>error: " + err);
}
}

</script>
```

The SSJS activity is running through, but no changes are being applied to the record in MobilePush Demographics. Anyone can help me out and tell what I am missing here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're not getting an error output in your catch block, but there isn't an HTTP.Patch function. You'd need to Script.Util.HttpRequest... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm

Comment: thanks @Macca for your reply. I am struggeling to understand what I need to change. Can you help me out here a bit more?